# When i select some text and click on share it will show my application

Tags: android

i want to build an android application.It is in such a way that when i selected some text and click on share it will show my application.Can anyone help me What i need to use and how i can get?

Comment: what you have done so far??? did you tyr something

Comment: Please show the Intent you fire. That might make things easier. Also perhaps your Manifest. It appears you may missing an intent-filter.

Comment: Yah i tried it.I created share button and default apps are showing in it.But i am not getting how to add my app...can you please help me

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Android that your app can handle text. You do that by defining intent filters in your Android manifest file.

eg:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here you are telling the system, that whenever anyone shares content of type "text/plain", Show my app as an option.

If the user selects your app, you will get the data in ui.MyActivity class as described below:

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }
    ...
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below intent filter to your activity in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter> >
    </activity>
```

here is the documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive